# VBA - copy / paste one cell from multiple workseets to master sheet

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I have code which opens multiple files in a folder, prints the name of that file into column 1 (continuing down the column) of a masterfile, closes the current file, and moves onto the next one until the folder is empty.

There is information in cell J1(preferably written as 1,10) of all of the files that I want to copy while the file is open, paste into column 4 (continuing down the column, equal with the names of each file), and continue to close the current file and move on.

I cannot figure out how to copy just one cell since a range requires information over multiple rows. Here is my working code for looping through files and just printing their name. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer

    'Speed up process by not updating the screen
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

    Set Sht = ActiveSheet

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 1
    'loop through directory file and print names
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" Or LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then
            'print file name
            Sht.Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
            i = i + 1
            Workbooks.Open fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name

        End If

        'Macro recording of manual copy/paste but I want to apply on general scale
        'Range("J1").Select
        'Selection.Copy
        'Windows("masterfile.xlsm").Activate
        'Range("D2").Select
        'ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Next objFile

'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorporate this, renaming "MySheet":

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyFromSheets()

    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
    i = 1

    With WB
        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            With ws
                .Range("J1").Copy Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("MySheet").Cells(i, 10) 'Rename Mysheet
                i = i + 1
            End With
        Next ws
    End With
End Sub
```

This should do it:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim Sht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

    Set Sht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("MySheet")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 1
    'loop through directory file and print names
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" Or LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then
            'print file name

            Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & objFile.Name
            Set WB = ActiveWorkbook

            With WB
                For Each ws In .Worksheets
                    Sht.Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
                    With ws
                        .Range("J1").Copy Sht.Cells(i + 1, 4)
                    End With
                    i = i + 1
                Next ws
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
    Next objFile

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for helping me out! The Line `.Range("J1").Copy Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("MySheet").Cells(i, 10)` comes back as out of range error. 
Just to clarify, I am copy from J1 in the worksheets to column 4 in the workbook titled "masterfile.xlsm". That's what this code is aiming towards, yes?

Comment: Ok amended to copy from col10 to col4, added full solution and changed MyFolder back to original. You will need to change the value of "MySheet" to the corresponding sheet name of masterfile.  In addition, this loops through each sheet in the files that are opened, so if this is not required, just remove the `For Each ws In .Worksheets` and `Next ws` if there is only one sheet in each workbook.

Comment: Ah! Fantastic! Works wonderfully! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You've already helped me so much but if you happen to know how to do a similar thing - copy the columns under a specific header and move it to the mastersheet - i've been struggling for about a week with that. If you could offer any help that would be amazing! The link to that question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30600381/search-for-column-header-copy-column-and-paste-to-master-workbook